# ATM using data structure without database and filehandling

Tags: java, swing

I created array list of customer class.store data using joptionpane. how i can get data at specific index of arraylist for udpating customer data.
here its my customer class

```
  public class Customer_Data {
       public int account_num,starting_balance=0 ;
       public String pincode="",name="",type="",account_num1="";
       public Object status;
    }
```

its admin class for create delete and update customer.

```
 public class ADMIN extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ADMIN
     */
    public ADMIN() {
        this.user = new ArrayList<Customer_Data>();
        initComponents();
    }
    List<Customer_Data> user;
    public void create_account() {
        Customer_Data a = new Customer_Data();
        a.account_num = (user.size() - 1)+1; 
        String[] s0 = {"Current", "Savings"};
        String[] s01 = {"Active", "Deactive"};
        String s = "";        a.name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name");
        String s1 = "";
        //a.pincode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter PinCode", s1);
        do {
            a.pincode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 digit PinCode", s1);            
        } while (!a.pincode.matches("[0-9]{5}")); String s2="";
        s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Starting Balance ");
        a.starting_balance = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        //String s3 = "";
        a.status = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select Status...", "Status", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, s01, s01[0]);
        a.type = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select Type...", "Type", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, s0, s0[0]);
        user.add(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
            Customer_Data var = user.get(i);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var.account_num + "\n" + var.name + "\n" + var.pincode + "\n" + var.status + "\n" + var.type, "sad", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

how i can get data at specific index in search function

```
    public void Search() {
        String s1 = "", s2 = "";
        s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Account Number u want to ", s2);
        for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
            if (user.contains(s1)) {
                for (int u = 0; u < user.indexOf(i); u++) {
                    Customer_Data var = user.get(u);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var.account_num + "\n" + var.name + "\n" + var.pincode + "\n" + var.status + "\n" + var.type, "sad", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Fount");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is mainly about search function, I'll try to demonstrate how you can fix it. Check out the `Search()` function in below program.

I'm looping over the `Customer_Data` list only once. For each `Customer_Data` in the list, I get `account_num` and compare it with user inputted value.

To avoid confusions, I did not change any identifier name you have used. But I strongly recommend you to use Java naming conventions. E.g:
Use `Admin` instead of `ADMIN`
Use `CustomerData` instead of `Customer_Data`
Use `search()` instead of `Search()`
Use `accountNum` instead of `account_num` etc.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ADMIN {

  private List<Customer_Data> user;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ADMIN admin = new ADMIN();
    admin.user = new ArrayList<>();

    Customer_Data customer1 = new Customer_Data();
    customer1.account_num = 123;
    customer1.name = "Kevin";
    admin.user.add(customer1);

    Customer_Data customer2 = new Customer_Data();
    customer2.account_num = 456;
    customer2.name = "Sally";
    admin.user.add(customer2);

    Customer_Data customer3 = new Customer_Data();
    customer3.account_num = 789;
    customer3.name = "Peter";
    admin.user.add(customer3);

    admin.Search();
  }

  public void Search() {
    String s1 = "", s2 = "";
    s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Account Number u want to ", s2);
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
      Customer_Data var = user.get(i);
      if (var.account_num == Integer.parseInt(s1)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var.account_num + "\n" + var.name, "sad", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Fount");
    }
  }
}

class Customer_Data {
  public int account_num,starting_balance=0 ;
  public String pincode="",name="",type="",account_num1="";
  public Object status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `List<E>` method `listOject.indexOf(theSearchObject)` is what you are looking for .
it return an `int` as the first matching occurance index or -1 if it's not contained .